# how to design one xml layout for all devices without creating folders or different sized images.

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design app in which i am using one xml layout,I want to use that layout for every device but i dont want to create new folders for small,large or extra large images in drawable.
how we can design one layout which is fit to all devices without creating images for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put that layout in the 'layout' folder and your image in 'drawable' folder, one place  no more :)
Android system will auto scale resource for you. But the UI will look bad.

Comment: Is it looks good for all devices? I am developing my app for all type of resolutions of android devices.